# ValueError: `logits` and `labels` must have the same shape, received ((None, 1) vs (None, 50))

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network

I am trying to implement Artificial Neural Network (ANN) and using Keras to predict Cloud Scheduling. Also, I am using some hyperparameters to design the ANN i am going to share my code and the error that occurred during the training of ANN.
My Hyperparameters [ num_iterations = 500, learning_rate = 0.1, num_neurons_input_layer = 2,num_neurons_output_layer = 1, num_hidden_layers = 2, num_hidden_units = 6

```
 import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers, models


num_tasks = 50
num_virtual_machines = 50
num_features_per_task = 2  
num_features_per_vm = 2  


task_features = np.random.rand(num_tasks, num_features_per_task)
vm_features = np.random.rand(num_virtual_machines, num_features_per_vm)


labels = np.random.randint(2, size=(num_tasks, num_virtual_machines))


assert num_tasks == num_virtual_machines, "Number of tasks and virtual machines should match."


num_iterations = 500
learning_rate = 0.1
num_neurons_input_layer = 2
num_neurons_output_layer = num_virtual_machines  
num_hidden_layers = 2
num_hidden_units = 6

model = models.Sequential()

# Input layer
model.add(layers.Dense(num_neurons_input_layer, activation='relu', input_shape=(num_features_per_task + num_features_per_vm,)))

# Hidden layers
for _ in range(num_hidden_layers):
    model.add(layers.Dense(num_hidden_units, activation='relu'))

# Output layer
model.add(layers.Dense(num_neurons_output_layer, activation='sigmoid'))

# Compile the model
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Combine task and VM features into a single input array
combined_features = np.hstack((task_features, vm_features))

# Train the model
model.fit(combined_features, labels, epochs=num_iterations, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.2)
```

while training model this error shows

```
   Epoch 1/500
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-6add7c62c493> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 model.fit(combined_features, labels, epochs=num_iterations, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.2)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py in tf__train_function(iterator)
     13                 try:
     14                     do_return = True
---> 15                     retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
     16                 except:
     17                     do_return = False

ValueError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1401, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1384, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1373, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1151, in train_step
        loss = self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 1209, in compute_loss
        return self.compiled_loss(
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/engine/compile_utils.py", line 277, in __call__
        loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/losses.py", line 143, in __call__
        losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/losses.py", line 270, in call  **
        return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/losses.py", line 2532, in binary_crossentropy
        backend.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred, from_logits=from_logits),
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/src/backend.py", line 5822, in binary_crossentropy
        return tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(

    ValueError: `logits` and `labels` must have the same shape, received ((None, 1) vs (None, 50)).
```